# Convert html string to pdf using wkhtmltopdf C library (wkhtmltox)

Tags: html, c++, c, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to convert **html string** to pdf using wkhtmltopdf C library. I checked the sample that comes together with the installer and I successfully compiled and converted the page. Here is the code that I used for reference.

```
wkhtmltopdf_global_settings * gs;
wkhtmltopdf_object_settings * os;
wkhtmltopdf_converter * c;

wkhtmltopdf_init(false);

gs = wkhtmltopdf_create_global_settings();

wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(gs, "out", "test.pdf");

os = wkhtmltopdf_create_object_settings();

wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(os, "page", "https://www.google.com.ph");

c = wkhtmltopdf_create_converter(gs);

wkhtmltopdf_set_progress_changed_callback(c, progress_changed);

wkhtmltopdf_set_phase_changed_callback(c, phase_changed);

wkhtmltopdf_set_error_callback(c, error);

wkhtmltopdf_set_warning_callback(c, warning);

wkhtmltopdf_add_object(c, os, NULL);

if (!wkhtmltopdf_convert(c))
    fprintf(stderr, "Convertion failed!");

printf("httpErrorCode: %d\n", wkhtmltopdf_http_error_code(c));

wkhtmltopdf_destroy_converter(c);

wkhtmltopdf_deinit();
```

I am suspecting that changing the parameters of the function

```
   wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(os, "page", "https://www.google.com.ph");
```

to something like

```
   wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(os, [name of setting], [html string]);
```

will do the job, however the documentation didn't specify any name for a particular setting aside from the one included in the sample which is "page".

Maybe I missed it in the documentation or maybe this is not the right way to do it. Any suggestion will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi EMP, here is a link to the settings [link]http://wkhtmltopdf.org/libwkhtmltox/pagesettings.html#pagePdfGlobal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks you for your time looking into this. I ended up with workaround. Instead of string i passed the local path of an generated html file. Its not the solution that I am looking for but it does the same thing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

```
void wkhtmltopdf_add_object(wkhtmltopdf_converter * converter,
       wkhtmltopdf_object_settings * settings, const char * data)
```

You can provide non-null `data` parameter pointing to *UTF-8 encoded* HTML string that will be converted to PDF instead of `page` setting.

Answer (score 1):

Yaroslav had the right idea.

Use the wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(os, "page", data) function but instead of a string representing a website URL, prefix your HTML string with a data URI.

For example:

```
const char *pszText = "data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><HTML><HEAD> .... </HTML>";

wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(os, "page", pszText);
```

Works like a champ. I even embedded small images in the page with div.*x*:before specifying a data:image/png;base64 as the content url.

Answer (score 0):

```
wkhtmltopdf_add_object(c, os, NULL);
```

Instead of passing NULL you can provide actual string data of html you want to convert.
And in Object Settings you can even not set "page" property.